# How can I store PHP code inside a 'heredoc' variable?

Tags: php

I would like to store the following code inside a HEREDOC variable:

```
<?php
    $var = 'test';
    echo $var;
?>
```

like this:

```
$hered = <<<HERED
<?php
    $var = 'test';
    echo $var;
?>
HERED;
```

The problem is that HEREDOC works like double quotes, `""` - that means each dollar sign (`$`) has to be replaced with `\$`...

Is there a way to use HEREDOC without performing such an operation?

Comment: The question should be: why do you want to do this? What you are doing here looks like code smell to me.

Comment: If you're doing this to `eval` later: please don't!

Answer (score 22):

Yes, there is. Check out the [nowdoc](http://php.net/nowdoc) syntax:

```
$hello = 'hey';
$echo <<<'EOS'
$hello world!
EOS;
//Output: $hello world
```

Comment: PHP 5.2 reached end of life 2.5 years ago. There are no more security updates to that old PHP versions since then, so anyone still running PHP before 5.3 should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: But how to do that with heredoc?

Comment: @simPod why would you? From the docs: `Nowdocs are to single-quoted strings what heredocs are to double-quoted strings. A nowdoc is specified similarly to a heredoc, but no parsing is done inside a nowdoc. The construct is ideal for embedding PHP code or other large blocks of text without the need for escaping.`http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc

Comment: @Xatenev because you might need parsing partially done so you need heredoc.

Comment: @simPod Sounds like you need a template engine.

Comment: @EmilVikström nope, I'm just dynamically composing medium SQL query

Answer (score 7):

It can be done using `\`:

```
echo <<<HEREDOC
<?php
    \$var = 'test';
    echo \$var;
?>
HEREDOC;
```

I know there's now doc, but for example my current use case needs heredoc, because some dollars need to be escaped and some not:

```
$variableNotToEscape = 'this should be output';
echo <<<HEREDOC
$variableNotToEscape
\$variableNotToEscape
HEREDOC;
```

Which returns

```
this should be output
$variableNotToEscape
```